# How to compress the BMP while converting to raw data in ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick

I'm working on converting RAW data to BMP and vice versa with `ImageMagick`. The program lanaguage is `Python`

The problem is the RAW DATA which was converted from BMP is larger than original one.

I need to get the same size or smaller one.

While converting the BMP to RAW Data, I applied the **Compress** but there was no effect.

Here are steps how I convert the RAW data to BMP and vice versa.

- RAW Data -> BMP

```
...
subprocess.check_call(['convert',
    '-size', str(obj['Width']) + 'x' + str(obj['Height']),
    '-depth', str(obj['BitsPerComponent']),
    '-type', 'truecolor',
    raw_data,
    'BMP3:' + bmp])
...
```

- BMP -> RAW Data

```
...
subprocess.check_call([
    'convert',
    '-depth',
    str(obj['BitsPerComponent']),
    '-compress',
    'RLE',
    bmp,
    raw_data
])
...
```

ImageMagick has following values for compress method.

> Choices are: None, BZip, Fax, Group4, JPEG, JPEG2000, Lossless, LZW, RLE or Zip.

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but normally raw data is raw data *(not compressed)*, so I don't clearly understand what are you trying to achieve applying compression on raw data.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Raw data is uncompressed. So if you compress BMP and generate raw data is will uncompress.